# Jquery: trigger 'click' on 'mouseout' dynamically

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I know the question seems very easy however it is not.

Please allow me to elaborate

**Task**
Bind *dynamically provided events with dynamically provided elements to raise dynamically provided events.*

I know the above task is as confusing as it looks. So in order to do it I have written some code and as it seems its not working. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Many thanks

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/a86HS2taz4G4Iiaijoqu?p=preview)

I have 3 variables

```
var elementId = 't'; /// the id of an element on which the binding is performed
var triggerOn = 'mouseout'; /// the event that is going to be bind
var triggerEvent = 'click'; /// the event that is going to be raised on the occurrence of the above event


///function that is binding the event with element
var triggeror = function (eleId, trgOn, TrgEve, isBind) {

    /// if isbind is true then bind else unbind
    if (isBind === true) {
        $('#' + eleId).bind(trgOn, triggerFun);  /// problem
    }
    else {
        $('#' + eleId).unbind(trgOn, triggerFun); /// problem 
    }

    var self = this;

    /// the event that is fired with the binded event is occured
    function triggerFun() {
        $('#' + self.eleId).trigger(self.TrgEve); ///trigger the another event
    }
};



/// fired when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function () {

    /// on text box click show an alert and un bind the trigeror
    $("#t").bind('click', function () {
        /// showing alert
        alert();
        /// unbinding
        triggeror(elementId, triggerOn, triggerEvent, false);
    });

    /// bind the mouseout to click on textbox
    triggeror(elementId, triggerOn, triggerEvent, true);
});
```

**Problem**
The event is not getting raised

Comment: For anyone opening the Plunkr, be ready for a barrage of alerts.

Comment: @SatejS I opened and then scrolled down.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed

https://plnkr.co/edit/6JQpvPkcRtw0qw2J2amv?p=preview

```
//triggeror(elementId, triggerOn, triggerEvent, false);
```

There were some problems like:

unbind after first click

bind, rebind, rebind.

When binding, you were calling the function instead of linking to it

```
$('#' + eleId).bind(trgOn,triggerFun(eleId, TrgEve));
```

changed to

```
$('#' + eleId).bind(trgOn,function(){ triggerFun(eleId, TrgEve) });
```

check out and let me know

Comment: unbinding is not working. Console log is logging everytime on mouse out

Comment: I commented it in the click event, I tough it was an error, not a "one-shot" event, uncomment it and you're done

Comment: sir, I have gone to the link that you have provided and its giving `triggerFun ["t", "click"]
index.js:35 click on t
index.js:24 triggerFun ["t", "click"]
index.js:35 click on t
index.js:24 triggerFun ["t", "click"]
index.js:35 click on t
index.js:24 triggerFun ["t", "click"]
index.js:35 click on t`

Comment: by the way, can you clarify when the unbind must be called ? you are telling me that is a one shot operation = unbind when the click is triggered, but in another comment you said that is non oneshot. please, clarify

Comment: I can be one-shot or a 1000 shot depend on the counter is passed as a parameter. this is only a dummy that I have created to show the problem that I am facing. Actually, if the counter surpass the limit of the count then the trigger should be unbinded.

Comment: ok, so where I commented the unbind, you manage it with a global counter

Comment: yes that is what exactly I am going to do. Please confirm one more thing. Suppose that there is already a same event is already bind with the element that I am going to bind dynamically. So, when we unbind then both events will be unbind?? is that so?? if yes then its a problem for me.

Comment: It depends on how the other event is bound, check the unbind function in the documentation of jquery, you can specify a named handler to unbind more precisely

Comment: as I though, all the events attached are getting removed with the call of unbind. I need to remove only the event that is bind dynamically. Please help. if I am passing named function with parameters then its getting called at the same point of time.

Comment: Just copy the bind function at row 11 and change to unbind, specifying the same handler should unbind only that

Comment: as you said I have replaced `$('#' + eleId).unbind(trgOn);` with `$('#' + eleId).unbind(trgOn, function(){
          triggerFun(eleId, TrgEve);
        });` but unbind is not working now . Many pardons and many thanks for the pain you are taking.

Comment: Instead of calling the bind and the unbind, I call the .one() and then if your counter says yes, reattach the event with another .one()

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your plunkr is your functions in your bind events are getting called instantly.

try adding them in a function like so:-

```
var triggeror = function (eleId, trgOn, TrgEve, isBind) {

    /// if isbind is true then bind else unbind
    if (isBind === true) {
        $('#' + eleId).bind(trgOn, function(){
          triggerFun(eleId, TrgEve);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#' + eleId).unbind(trgOn);
    }
};
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3gsEOfRnHjHskSQFbJqR)

**NOTE:**

> **.bind()**
>
> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: I think there's no need to add an handler to the unbind function

Comment: Sir, Unbinding is still not working. Its is getting called everytime the mouseout is called